# I want to count dish names at specific dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `order_details` table and in that I have an `item` column. In that column I have values like below. I am using PHP and mysql for backend.

```
Item
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2017-02-09_chicken masala, 2017-02-10_RAJMA, 2017-02-11_ROTI, 2017-02-13_BENGAN MASALA, 2017-02-14_DAAL 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

2017-02-06_CHAWAL,2017-02-07_RAJMA,2017-02-08_ROTI,2017-02-09_BENGAN MASALA,2017-02-10_DAAL
```

From that I want to make a report of dish names between two dates, but the problem is that dish names are associated with date. Please help me - I am new to this.

Comment: You want to extract dishes that come between, for example, `2017-02-06` and `2017-02-10`?

Comment: yes, when i will give range of dates, i want to calculate dishes present in between that two dates and then count each dish count to show report

Comment: did u get it Perumal93.I need the exact solution

Comment: Yeah. I got it what you mean.

Comment: Do u have any idea about how to do that because between query not working on that . This is the query    $qry="SELECT prefixed_date_item as item from order_details WHERE prefixed_date_item BETWEEN '".$post_data['date']."' AND  '".$post_data['end_date']." '  AND type='customized'  AND store_id='".$post_data['store_id']."' ";

Comment: As your `item` column has your own structure for storing multiple orders, this  might be feasible with regular expression. There is a mysql function named `REGEXP` meant for extract string with provided regular expression.

Comment: but here i want date range,i dont just want to match date

Answer (score 0):

start by organizing your data in your table,have a column for Date with data type as date,and a column for dishname  with datatype var-char and column for  primary key,primary key use an int and set it to auto increment. that way you only need to query the data using

Select * from tablename where date >='date1' and date <='date2';

Comment: Thats not possible now because i want that structure to show at front end  user3417276

Answer (score 0):

I've written the code with user-defined function to extract those ordered items between two dates. This is the code you can use to achieve you what you're looking for.

```
function get_dishes($dishes_str, $from_date, $to_date) {
    $dishes_str_explode = explode(",", $dishes_str);
    $dishes_str_explode = array_map(function($v) {
        return trim($v);
    }, $dishes_str_explode);

    $dishes = array();

    foreach($dishes_str_explode as $dish) {
        $dish_explode = explode("_", $dish);
        $dishes[] = $dish_explode;
        unset($dish_explode);
    }

    $dishes_extracted = array_map(function($v) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        if(strtotime($v[0]) >= strtotime($from_date) && strtotime($v[0]) <= strtotime($to_date)) {
            return $v;
        }
    }, $dishes);

    return array_values(array_filter($dishes_extracted));
}

$dishes = array(
    "2017-02-09_chicken masala, 2017-02-10_RAJMA, 2017-02-11_ROTI, 2017-02-13_BENGAN MASALA, 2017-02-14_DAAL",
    "2017-02-06_CHAWAL,2017-02-07_RAJMA,2017-02-08_ROTI,2017-02-09_BENGAN MASALA,2017-02-10_DAAL"
);

$dishes_out = get_dishes($dishes[0], "2017-02-12", "2017-02-14");

foreach($dishes_out as $dish) {
    // Output with formatted date
    // echo "<p>Date: " . date_format(new DateTime($dish[0]), 'd-m-Y') . "<br>Dish: {$dish[1]}</p>";

    // Ouput with as-is date
    echo "<p>Date: {$dish[0]}<br>Dish: {$dish[1]}</p>";
}

echo "<p>Total dishes: " . count($dishes_out) . "</p>";
```

Let me know in the comment if you need any explanations of the code.

By the way, the code might seem to be experiencing code smell and it can be written better if refactoring is done.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

$date_from = '2017-02-09';
$date_to = '2017-02-13';

$sql = "SELECT SUBSTR(item,1,10) as dates,SUBSTR(item,12) as dishname FROM order_details WHERE SUBSTR(item,1,10) >".$date_from." AND SUBSTR(item,1,10) <=".$date_to ;

Execute this sql and you will get your desired output.